# Generate files from xml for each node

Tags: php, file

I would like to generate files from xml, I try this but it not working:

```
<?php
$file0 = "fle0.php";
$file1 = "fle1.php";
$file2 = "fle2.php";
$file3 = "fle3.php";
$file4 = "fle4.php";
$file5 = "fle5.php";
$file6 = "fle6.php";
$file7 = "fle7.php";
$file8 = "fle8.php";
$file9 = "fle9.php";
$html = "";
$url = "http://website.com/file.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
$link = $xml->books[$i]->link;
$title = $xml->books[$i]->title;
$html .= "<a href=\"$link\">$title</a>";
file_put_contents($file[$i], $html);
}
?>
```

Can I use file_put_contents in for loop?

Here is the XML file:

```
<response>

<books>
<link>http:/www.website.com/linktobook/1.html</link>
<title>Book Title 1</title>
<image>http:/www.website.com/linktobook/1.jpg</image>
</books>

<books>
<link>http:/www.website.com/linktobook/2.html</link>
<title>Book Title 2</title>
<image>http:/www.website.com/linktobook/2.jpg</image>
</books>

<books>
<link>http:/www.website.com/linktobook/3.html</link>
<title>Book Title 3</title>
<image>http:/www.website.com/linktobook/3.jpg</image>
</books>

</response>
```

It is working without loop when I use $xml->books[0]->link; and $xml->books[1]->link; etc.

Comment: provide file.xml code in question for proper code testing and answer from users

Comment: `$file[$i]` doesn't exist (it's not an array), you probably meant `${"file$i"}`.

Comment: Thank you Jack! It is working! One more time :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to: Jack

The answer is: change $file[$i] to ${"file$i"}